# Keras, print metrics only for validation data

Tags: keras

Sorry for the trivial question, please point me to a better source if this is not the proper place.

Is there a way to print keras metrics only for validation_data?

I'd like to track a couple of epoch specific metrics (e.g. precision, recall and f1 score). There are a couple of handy methods for them available in keras git history, but they make no sense when computed batch-wise at training time, while they do at test/validation time.

So the training metrics are just cluttering my logs for nothing. Is there a way to mute them?

EDIT: I know I can subclass `Callback` and only do those on epoch end, but that way I'm doing two predictions on validation data per epoch, one in my callback and one done by keras under the hood to compute validation loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ProgbarLogger` callback is added to the model only if `verbose > 0`. In the source code [training.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py):

```py
if verbose:
    if steps_per_epoch is not None:
        count_mode = 'steps'
    else:
        count_mode = 'samples'
    callbacks += [cbks.ProgbarLogger(count_mode)]
```

So a possible workaround is:

- Specify `verbose=0` in `fit()` to suppress the built-in `ProgbarLogger`
- Subclass `ProgbarLogger` and change the code to ignore the training metrics
- Add this callback when calling `fit()`

For example,

```py
from keras.callbacks import ProgbarLogger

class ValOnlyProgbarLogger(ProgbarLogger):
    def __init__(self, verbose, count_mode='samples'):
        # Ignore the `verbose` argument specified in `fit()` and pass `count_mode` upstream
        self.verbose = verbose
        super(ValOnlyProgbarLogger, self).__init__(count_mode)

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        # filter out the training metrics
        self.params['metrics'] = [m for m in self.params['metrics'] if m.startswith('val_')]
        self.epochs = self.params['epochs']

input_tensor = Input(shape=(256,))
out = Dense(10)(input_tensor)
model = Model(input_tensor, out)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae', 'cosine'])
model.fit(X, Y, validation_data=(XX, YY), verbose=0,
          callbacks=[ValOnlyProgbarLogger(verbose=1)])
```

The training metrics will now be suppressed:

```py
Epoch 1/1
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 392us/step - val_loss: 0.2479 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.3988 - val_cosine_proximity: -0.7022
```

Note that if you're using `fit_generator` instead of `fit`, you'll need to specify `count_mode='steps'` when initializing `ValOnlyProgbarLogger`.

Comment: Thanks, that will work pretty fine. It would be great though if I could skip training metrics computations at all so I could do more complex stuff only at validation time and not slow down training with them. I guess I will have to weight the cost of extra metric computations at training time against that of an extra prediction on epoch end.

Comment: Hi, I got attribute error says no self.params in ValOnlyProgbarLogger. Do you get any experience for this? I am using TF 2.2